# Can't get my android app use facebook although after putting my hash keys

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have changed my eclipse to another version after a sever crash. Now I can't get my apps log to Facebook or post either a text or an image.

I know how to generate the debug.keystore hash key, and my Keystore hash key which I export my apps using it.
BTW  I deleted my `debug.keystore` and generate a new one as a try to solve the problem, I failed.

Here is the command used for `debug.keystore`:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\keytool.exe" -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
>   C:\Users\Administrator.android\debug.keystore |
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\openssl.exe sha1 -binary |
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\openssl.exe base64

Also this is my Keystore which I use to export my apps into:

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\keytool.exe" -exportcert -alias
>   exportkeystore -keystore "C:\Users\Administrator\APKs\exportkeystore"
>   | C:\Windows\SysWOW64\openssl.exe sha1 -binary |
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\openssl.exe base64

I put the resulted two hash keys, into my Facebook android native app.
Also I have noticed that my eclipse SHA has changed to another one, my previous eclipse was Juno and the present is Kepler.

Now, what is the solution?
How to solve my Facebook login problem? and
Can I still publish my apps after the eclipse fingerprint certificate changed (i.e. new SHA) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my question, referred to the official Facebook API documentation:
[Setting a Release Key Hash](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling below method from onCreate api of first Activity of your app. It will print a Hash Key, compare that with the HASH you added into Facebook application and see if this is the problem

```
 public void printHashKey() {

    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("your.package.name",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("TEMPTAGHASH KEY:",
                    Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, the resulted hash key is the same of my Facebook app. The problem still not resolved.
Btw, thank you.

Still need to know if a different eclipse SHA would let me publish my apps to Google Play.